# AngularJS Toolbar Button Tooltip Showing When Closing Sidenav

Tags: angularjs, tooltip

I  have just started learning AngularJS and have created a header using md-toolbar. I have 3 buttons (Home, About and Enquiries) Each button has a tooltip that displays when hovered over. The 'Enquiries' button opens a sidenav. However, when I close the sidenav the 'Enquiries' button tooltip redisplays and does not fadeout. If I move the sidenav function call to the 'About' button, the same thing happens. It looks like the button that opened the sidenav will have it's tooltip redisplayed when the sidenav that it opened is closed. Any ideas on a solution please?

Comment: please provide the essential parts of your code

Comment: **This is the code for the button that opens the sidenav form**: <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="openEnquiryForm()">
     <md-icon class="mdi mdi-email"></md-icon>
     <md-tooltip md-direction="bottom" md-delay="0.3">Send Us A Query</md-tooltip>
     Enquiries
    </md-button>

Comment: Change the opacity feature in the tooltip.scss